# How to install react native app into my own smartphone device

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am currently learning mobile app development by using react native. I am using 'EXPO CLI' to simulate the code on my device/emulator. However, after reading the react-native official documentation, I realize that the steps required 'Android' folder in my project that does not exist because I did not run 'npm run eject'.

May I know is there any source on how to install my app into my device locally?
(Meaning no longer running the app through EXPO).

Comment: You can see here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started - Navigate to the 'Building Projects with Native Code' tab

Comment: Do i need to run npm eject to eject from expo? which i am still not sure what is the relationship between expo and react-native. The new update on Expo is so confusing

Comment: no, do not eject. have you read https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/guides/testing-on-devices and https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/guides/building-standalone-apps.html ?

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll try to go through the link you attached first. I've missed that part.

Comment: Thank you for that attachment. I can now generate the apk and install in my own device without using EXPO as a wrapper. Thank you very much